# Querying and Filtering Array of JObjects with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I suppose this is another entry in my series of questions, but I'm stuck again. This time, I'm having trouble working with a JArray of JObjects and determining the Property.Value type for each element in the JArray...

My code is here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/bRcSAQ

The difference between my previous questions and this question is that my outer Linq query gets both JObject and JArray tokens, so that's why I have an `if (jo is JObject)` at Line 40 and a `if (jo is JArray)` at Line 48.

Once I know I have a JArray of `<JObjects>`, I have code that looks like this (Lines 48-):

```
    if (jo is JArray)
    {
        var items = jo.Children<JObject>();                     
        // return a JObject object
    }
```

When I use a debugger and look at items, I see that it contains 3 JObject objects--one for Item_3A1, Item_3A2, and Item3A3. But I need to know the JTokenType for each JProperty.Value because I am interested only in Property values of type JTokenType.String.

So I tried:

```
// doesn't work :(
var items = jo.Children<JObject>()
              .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String);
```

The compiler red-lines the Value property with the error `CS0119 'JToken.Value<T>(object)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context.`

I realize that "p" in the Linq express is not a JProperty. I guess it's a JObject. And I don't know how to cast "p" so that I can examine the type of JProperty object it represents.

Ultimately, I need the code for JArray processing (starting at Line 48) to add an return a JObject that contains an JSON array composed only of JProperty objects of type JTokenType.String. This means that given the sample JSON, it first should return a JObject holding these JSON properties:

```
{ ""Item_3A1"": ""Desc_3A1"" },
{ ""Item_3A2"": ""Desc_3A2"" },
{ ""Item_3A3"": ""Desc_3A3"" }
```

On the next iteration, it should return a JObject holding these JSON properties (notice that the nested Array3B1 properties are omitted because Array3B1 is not a JProperty with a Value type of JTokenType.String):

```
{ ""Item_3B1"": ""Desc_3B1"" },
{ ""Item_3B2"": ""Desc_3B2"" },
```

The third iteration would contain:

```
{ ""Item_3B11"": ""Desc_3B11"" },
{ ""Item_3B12"": ""Desc_3B12"" },
{ ""Item_3B13"": ""Desc_3B13"" }
```

And the fourth (final) iteration would contain:

```
{ ""Item_3C1"": ""Desc_3C1"" },
{ ""Item_3C2"": ""Desc_3C2"" },
{ ""Item_3C3"": ""Desc_3C3"" }
```

This might be my final hurdle in this "series".

Sincere thanks to anyone who can and will help--and a special thanks again to users "Brian Rogers" and "dbc" for their truly amazing JSON.NET/Linq knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried to make p.Value. GetType ()  ?

Comment: Yes, but that did not help. The key was to use SelectMany() and tack a Where() to the end of that resultset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This produces the output you require:

```
var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(json);
var query = root.Descendants()
    .Where(jt => (jt.Type == JTokenType.Object) || (jt.Type == JTokenType.Array))
    .Select(jo =>
        {
            if (jo is JObject)
            {
                if (jo.Parent != null && jo.Parent.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                    return null;
                // No help needed in this section               
                // populate and return a JObject for the List<JObject> result 
                // next line appears for compilation purposes only--I actually want a populated JObject to be returned
                return new JObject();
            }

            if (jo is JArray)
            {
                var items = jo.Children<JObject>().SelectMany(o => o.Properties()).Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String);
                return new JObject(items);
            }
            return null;
        })
    .Where(jo => jo != null)
    .ToList();
```

Here I use [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten the nested enumeration of properties of the enumeration of child objects of `jo` to a single enumeration of all properties of child objects.  `o => o.Properties()` is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) mapping the `JObject o` to its collection of properties, and `p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String` is another lambda mapping a property `p` (generated by the previous `SelectMany` clause) to a true/false value indicating whether the property has a string value.  Both `o` and `p` are lambda input parameters that are [implicitly typed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx#Anchor_4).

Also, in the `// No help needed in this section` section, objects whose parents are arrays are skipped, since they will get collected by the `(jo is JArray)` clause.

Note that if different children of the `jo` array happen to have identical property names, the `JObject` constructor may throw a duplicated key exception.

Forked [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VHHan3).

Comment: Awesome, dbc. So is it correct to say that the o refers to a JObject (from Children()) and the p refers to a JProperty (from o.Properties())? If yes, that was my "missing linq". :)

Comment: In your forked fiddle results (after running), I see empty query items. How can I skip them? Would I add an any() modifier to the Linq expression? If so, where?

Comment: @Jazimov - OK, looks like you did need help in the `No help needed` section.  I'd recommend skipping all objects whose parents are arrays since they will get collected in the subsequent `if (jo is JArray)` clause.

Comment: Well, in all fairness, I was not running the code that's in the No help needed section and it does in fact skip as needed (it also processes other non-array JSON but wasn't listed because it wasn't relevant to the question in this post). Apologies for the follow up question. :) May I ask for one final comment from you on my first comment? Then I'm on my way. Thank you again!