# JSON.NET: Flattening a JArray to JObjects within Linq Query

Tags: linq, json.net

This is a follow-up to my earlier post, here:
[Querying and Filtering Array of JObjects with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670781/querying-and-filtering-array-of-jobjects-with-linq)

I posted a dotnetfiddle here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/s75wGu

***Apologies, but I couldn't figure out why I'm getting an error on System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable in dotnetfiddle, but the program works under Linqpad and Visual Studio.***

The source JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Object": {
    "NM": "Name1",
    "AA": "Val01",
    "BB": "Val02",
    "CC": "Val03",
    "DD": "Val04",
    "EE": "Val05",
    "FF": "Val06",
    "GG": "Val07",
    "HH": "Val08",
    "Object": [
      {
        "NM": "Name2",
        "AA": "Val01",
        "BB": "Val02",
        "CC": "Val03",
        "DD": "Val04",
        "EE": "Val05",
        "FF": "Val06",
        "GG": "Val07",
        "HH": "Val08",
        "Object": [
          {
            "NM": "Name3",
            "AA": "Val01",
            "BB": "Val02",
            "CC": "Val03",
            "DD": "Val04",
            "EE": "Val05",
            "FF": "Val06",
            "GG": "Val07",
            "HH": "Val08"
          },
          {
            "NM": "Name4",
            "AA": "Val01",
            "BB": "Val02",
            "CC": "Val03",
            "DD": "Val04",
            "EE": "Val05",
            "FF": "Val06",
            "GG": "Val07",
            "HH": "Val08"
          },
          {
            "NM": "Name5",
            "AA": "Val01",
            "BB": "Val02",
            "CC": "Val03",
            "DD": "Val04",
            "EE": "Val05",
            "FF": "Val06",
            "GG": "Val07",
            "HH": "Val08"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, the code is designed to query a JSON document and flatten it to a `List<JObject>` object.

The `if (jo is JObject)` clause should be straightforward: If the Linq iteration finds a JObject object, it creates a `joWork` JObject instance, adds properties to it, and returns the single `joWork` object. This works fine.

But my problem is working with the `if (jo is JArray)` clause: Here, I think that Linq expects me to return a single JObject object, but I've got an array of JObjects that I want to return as separate JObjects.

The output produced by my dotnetfiddle code is this:

```
joWork-Object: {
  "_Parent": "",
  "NM": "Name1",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name1",
  "_Group": 1,
  "NM": "Name2",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork: 
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name2",
  "_Group": 2,
  "NM": "Name5",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork: 
joWork: 
joWork:
```

Notice that we have Object Name (NM) Name1, Name2, then Name5 only. What I would like is to have Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, and Name5--each having a _Parent property that contains to the parent object's NM property.

I realize I'm getting only Name5 because the JArray if statement in my Linq query returns only the last element in the array. I would like to return all elements in the array. The final output should look like this:

```
joWork-Object: {
  "_Parent": "",
  "NM": "Name1",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name1",
  "_Group": 1,
  "NM": "Name2",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name2",
  "_Group": 2,
  "NM": "Name3",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name2",
  "_Group": 2,
  "NM": "Name4",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
joWork-Array: {
  "_Parent": "Name2",
  "_Group": 2,
  "NM": "Name5",
  "AA": "Val01",
  "BB": "Val02",
  "CC": "Val03",
  "DD": "Val04",
  "EE": "Val05",
  "FF": "Val06",
  "GG": "Val07",
  "HH": "Val08"
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Can you [edit] your question to create a full [mcve] of your problem?  At the moment your code doesn't compile.  Also, it would be helpful for you to show the full output desired, not just snippets.  And are you sure the second JSON snippet should not be `{ "Name" : "Array1B", .. ` ?

Comment: To confirm, you want to return *two identical `JObject` values* when visiting the `"Array1A"` array?

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I will create a running example and explain what I need. I should have that posted shortly. Thanks.

Comment: OK, question revised. I hope this time I've been more clear. I feel I'm 98% there--can't wait to see the solution!

Comment: You're getting the dotnetfiddle error because of this: https://dotnetfiddle.uservoice.com/forums/228764--net-fiddle-ideas/suggestions/10782315-load-the-specified-version-of-json-net-rather-than

Comment: OK, but I didn't see the fix--is one known?

Comment: Nope, as far as I know there's no workaround on dotnetfiddle.  Vote for the suggestion, maybe they will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) in place of [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to return multiple objects inside a linq query, flattening out the returned inner enumerable into its constituent objects for the overall enumeration:

```
        var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(jsonFromFile);

        var controlRoot = (JContainer)root["Object"];

        string parentKey = "";
        int groupId = 0;

        var query =
            controlRoot
            .DescendantsAndSelf()
            .Where(jt => (jt.Type == JTokenType.Object) || (jt.Type == JTokenType.Array))
            .SelectMany(jo =>
            {
                if (jo.Parent is JProperty)
                {
                    var ParentName = ((JProperty)jo.Parent).Ancestors()
                                    .Where(jt => jt.Type == JTokenType.Property)
                                    .Select(jt => ((JProperty)jt).Name.ToString())
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (ParentName == "Object")
                    {
                        parentKey = ((JProperty)jo.Parent).AncestorsAndSelf()   // Climb up the json container parent/child hierachy
                           .Select(p => p.SelectToken("NM"))                    // Get the "parentKey" property in the current parent (if present)
                           .FirstOrDefault(k => k != null).ToString();          // Return the first one found.
                    }

                    if (jo is JObject)
                    {
                        // add a property for the parent
                        var joWork = new JObject(new JProperty("_Parent", parentKey));

                        // add only the string properties in the current object
                        joWork.Add(((JObject)jo).Properties()
                            .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String));

                        return new[] { joWork };
                    }
                    else if (jo is JArray)
                    {
                        groupId++;
                        return from o in jo
                               let arrayItems = ((JObject)o).Properties().Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList()
                               where arrayItems.Count > 0
                               select new JObject(new[]
                                   {
                                       new JProperty("_Parent", parentKey),
                                       new JProperty("_Group", groupId),
                                   }
                                   .Concat(arrayItems));
                    }
                }
                return Enumerable.Empty<JObject>();
            }
            )
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query, Formatting.Indented));
```

Here I am using LINQ query syntax inside the `SelectMany()` method, since it's more compact.  The alternative method syntax would be:

```
                    else if (jo is JArray)
                    {
                        groupId++;
                        return jo.Select(o =>
                            {
                                var arrayItems = ((JObject)o).Properties()
                                    .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String).ToList();
                                if (arrayItems.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    var joWork = new JObject();

                                    // add a property for the parent
                                    joWork.Add(new JProperty("_Parent", parentKey));
                                    joWork.Add(new JProperty("_Group", groupId));

                                    // add only the string properties in the current object
                                    joWork.Add(arrayItems);
                                    return joWork;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            })
                            .Where(o => o != null);
                    }
```